# Insertar nuevo valor a consulta JSON en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

De antemano agradezco su ayuda; tengo una consulta a una tabla; esta consulta la paso a JSON con json_encode:

```
$sql = "SELECT npa.load_zone_data.zona_carga, npa.coordenadas_zona_carga.latitude, 
npa.coordenadas_zona_carga.longitude, TRUNCATE(AVG(npa.load_zone_data.$componente$mercado),2) as pml, npa.load_zone_data.fechahora 
      FROM npa.coordenadas_zona_carga
      INNER JOIN npa.load_zone_data ON npa.coordenadas_zona_carga.zona_carga = npa.load_zone_data.zona_carga
      WHERE npa.load_zone_data.zona_carga in ($estados) and npa.load_zone_data.fechahora='$fecha_query'
      group by npa.load_zone_data.zona_carga";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows >0) 
          {
              // aqui feutch los datos
          $final_array = array ();  
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())     
              {
              $arr = array('title'   =>$row['zona_carga'],
                          'latitude'   =>(float)$row['latitude'],
                          'longitude' =>(float)$row['longitude'],
                          'value' =>(float)$row['pml']
                          );
          $final_array [] = $arr;
              }
      //convierte los datos en formato json
      $json_data = json_encode ($final_array);
      ?>
```

Esto me regresa este JSON:

> [{"title":"ACAPULCO","latitude":16.852299,"longitude":-99.909317,"value":822.85},{"title":"AGUASCALIENTES","latitude":21.884501,"longitude":-102.292534,"value":822.85},{"title":"APATZINGAN","latitude":19.091169,"longitude":-102.350594,"value":822.85},{"title":"CABORCA","latitude":30.716249,"longitude":-112.160599,"value":822.85},{"title":"CAMARGO","latitude":27.685538,"longitude":-105.169995,"value":822.85},{"title":"CAMPECHE","latitude":18.840435,"longitude":-90.35997,"value":822.85},{"title":"CANCUN","latitude":21.160362,"longitude":-86.858159,"value":822.85},{"title":"CARMEN","latitude":18.653411,"longitude":-91.779335,"value":822.85},{"title":"CASAS GRANDES","latitude":30.401563,"longitude":-107.918448,"value":822.85}]

Lo que requiero es agregar el valor de `"colores": colorSet.next()`
Para que quede algo así:

```
{"title":"CARMEN","latitude":18.653411,"longitude":-91.779335,"value":822.85,"colores": colorSet.next()}
```

Gracias a todos por su apoyo.

Comment: Hay más de un colór para cada fila?

Comment: No, el valor que debe de tener es el mismo siempre 
"colores": colorSet.next()
asi sin "" el colorSet.next(), gracias.

Comment: Ok.  Por qué no lo pone dentro del array despues de 'value' =>(float)$row['pml'] ?

Comment: Hola gracias, la verdad es que no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Creo que como tal no puedes hacer eso. La conversión a json obligaría a ponerlo entre comillas dobles (por el propio formato json). Ese `colorSet.next()` es para que lo intérprete luego un JavaScript? Quizás sea mejor que le pongas un campo `color` con un valor y luego que el JavaScript o la parte front lea dicho valor y ponga el color correspondiente...

Comment: Ok amigo mira mi java es asi: var circle2 = imageSeries.mapImages.template.createChild(am4core.Circle);
circle2.radius = 4;
circle2.propertyFields.fill = "color";
color debe ser el valor de colorSet.next()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu código de ejemplo es sumamente fácil; lo único que necesitas es inyectar el nuevo dato en el ciclo while:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())     
{
    $arr = array(
        'title'      =>$row['zona_carga'],
        'latitude'   =>(float)$row['latitude'],
        'longitude'  =>(float)$row['longitude'],
        'value'      =>(float)$row['pml'],
        'colores'    => 'colorSet.next()' //inyección de los colores
    );
    $final_array [] = $arr;
}
```

como veras el método que citas: `colorSet.next()` debería estar en el php y de esta manera estarías pasando siempre el `json` con los colores.

esto va a provocar que tu json llegue pero la propiedad color se vera asi:

```
"colores":"colorSet.next"
```

Si quieres que se ejecute `colorSet.next()` de lado de javascript, entonces cuando iteres el json y leas las propiedades puedes invocar al método asi:

```
window[colores]();
```

***ejemplo Practico:***

```js
function pruebadellamada(){
  console.log('Hello World');
}

let functionName = 'pruebadellamada';

window[functionName]();
```

Comment: Mil gracias si la agrega efectivamente pero la requiero sin "" como se podria hacer? 
,{"title":"AGUASCALIENTES","latitude":21.884501,"longitude":-102.292534,"value":834.88,"color":"colorSet.next()"},
necesito algo asi 
,{"title":"AGUASCALIENTES","latitude":21.884501,"longitude":-102.292534,"value":834.88,"color":colorSet.next()},

Comment: a que te refieres sin comillas? en realidad php no guarda texto sin comillas solo numero enteros

Comment: si tienes un metodo en javascript que se llame de esa forma solo tienes que hacer esto window.[color] y te va a jalar y ejecutar la funcion ... que se llame colorSet.next()

Comment: tengo algo asi:
`circle2.propertyFields.fill = "color"; color debe ser el valor de colorSet.nex()`

Comment: ok y puedes agregar el contenido de colorSet.nex() si es una funcion o un metodo...

Comment: Me da que no lo necesitas realmente. Si lo que quieres es ejecutar `colorSet.next()` en tu Java... Por qué no lo ejecutas sin más? Algo como `circle2.propertyFields.fill = colorSet.next();`? No veo que necesidad tienes de enviar esa cadena desde php si luego es la ejecución de esa función en el Java para ponerle el color al circle2...